# Plot empty / cut off ..... way to force more computation?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I am trying to plot two functions in one Plot inside a Manipulate-environment. It works fine for "small" ranges of variable and parameter (1...100), but I need it around 5000 or so. When I do this, the plot leaves the visible range of the y-Axis. I tried to use "PlotRange -> Full", but then, upwards of a certain value (about 1000) for my parameter r, the plot suddenly becomes empty.

I guess it has something to do with too large computations, but is there any way to "force" Mathematica to do more / longer computations ... or any other way to plot these functions in a useable way for values of r=5000 and comparable?

---

My code for the Plot is

```
Manipulate[Plot[{2^(r(-((Log[Min[r - s, s]/r] Min[r - s, s])/(r Log[2])) - (Log[1 - Min[r - s, s]/r] (1 - Min[r - s, s]/r))/Log[2])), 
   K[2^r - 1]*2^(1/2 r (3/4 - (Log[Min[r - s, s]/r] Min[r - s, s])/(r Log[2]) - (Log[1 - Min[r - s, s]/r] (1 - Min[r - s, s]/r))/Log[2]))}, {s, 1, 5000}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotLegends -> {"L", "RK"}], {r, 1, 
  5000}]
```

and the function K is defined via

```
f[x_] := 4.9 x^(1/4);                                                 
g[x_] := 4514.7 x^(1/8);
h[x_] := x^(0.96/(Log[Log[x]]));
K[x_] := Min[f[x], g[x], h[x]]
```

Comment: I tried to run your code, but it is not properly structured. When I tried to fix it, I got the message: "2^(a+bI) is too small to represent as a normalized machine number". So there are likely two problems: underflow (use Chop) and trying to plot a complex number (use Abs).

Comment: @bills Sorry, it's my first time posting here and I'm unfamiliar with the Code-format options here ... I copied my Code straight out of Mathematica, and some parts went missing. The Manipulate[...] around everything for example .... I added it, and also the definition of the function K i am using. - 

There are no complex numbers involved, s should be a real variable, and r a real parameter, which I set in the Manipulate environment

Comment: The problem is the numbers are too large. You can get a possibly useful plot by taking the Log of everything... then the y axis has values of (say) 3000 rather than 2^3000. Just do Plot[ Log[{    } ] ] instead of Plot[ {    }  ]

Comment: @bills That works great, thank you! Only one last question, because I used PlotLegends to label which function is which, but now both are part of the same "Log" ... how can I make them distinguashable in the Plot?

Comment: It works if you do: Plot[ { Log( ), Log( ) } ] instead of Plot[ Log[{ } ] ]. Note that now you get one blue and one orange (instead of both blue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] := 49/10 x^(1/4);
g[x_] := 45147/10 x^(1/8);
h[x_] := x^((96/100)/(Log[Log[x]]));
K[x_] := Min[f[x], g[x], h[x]]
```

As pointed out in the comments by `bill s`, plot the log of the functions. Also, for the lower values of `r` you probably want to use [`LogLinearPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLinearPlot.html)

```
Manipulate[
 min = Min[r - s, s];
 funcs = N[{2^(r (-((Log[min/r] min)/(r Log[2])) - (Log[
             1 - min/r] (1 - min/r))/Log[2])),
    K[2^r - 
       1]*2^(1/2 r (3/
           4 - (Log[min/r] min)/(r Log[2]) - (Log[1 - min/r] (1 - min/r))/
           Log[2]))}, 20];
 plt[Evaluate@Log[funcs], {s, 1, 5000},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {s, Log}),
  WorkingPrecision -> 15,
  PlotRange -> Full,
  PlotLegends -> {"L", "RK"}],
 {{plt, Plot, "type of plot"}, {Plot, LogLinearPlot}},
 {{r, 2000}, 25, 5000, 25, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {plt, r}]
```

[image]